# The mail command hangs on "Cc:" for mail

Tags: command-line, email, aws, amazon

For some reason, when I send mail with
`mail -s 'test email' tomyrealemail@myrealwebsite.com`
It prints out `Cc:` after I press enter and I can't do anything. I tried pressing `.` and it still is stuck. I'm trying to setup Amazon SES on Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried to press Enter ?

Comment: Don't use the `mail` program. There's no need to. If you want to send mail by a human user, use "real" email client like `mutt`. If you want to send mail programatically from script, use `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, as `mail` internally does. In both cases the `mail` program is unneeded.

Comment: Im getting this and I notice none of the answers address it.

Answer (score 26):

It is not hung.  It is waiting for you to type in your message.  Normally you can just send a command line email like:

```
echo "This is a test message" | mail -s 'test email' tomyrealemail@myrealwebsite.com
```

But if you just do `mail -s 'test email' tomyrealemail@myrealwebsite.com` the next part will be the `Cc:` or Carbon Copy email. If none, just press Enter.

Then just type in whatever body to the message you want to send, then as soon as you are done press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send the message.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can just put '< /dev/null' ate the end of your command like this:

```
mail -s 'test email' tomyrealemail@myrealwebsite.com < /dev/null
```

It will send your message without any body.